# how to make qplot produce a line plot with one vector of data

Tags: r, ggplot2

`qplot` uses histogram by default when you only provide one vector of data. For example, `qplot(1:100)` will produce a histogram. However, adding `geom="line"` won't work. So, my question is, how can I use `qplot` to generate the same kind of plot as the command `plot(1:100)`, which is a line plot? Thanks in advance.

I know you can manually add a dummy index as the x, but that seems cluttered. Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I run `plot(1:100)`, I get a points plot with x = seq_along(y), y = 1:100

to get the same plot using `qplot`, all you need to run is

```
plot(1:100)
```

[image]

```
qplot(y = 1:100)
```

[image]

Within `qplot` there is

```
if (missing(x)) {
                aesthetics$x <- bquote(seq_along(.(y)), aesthetics)
            }
            geom[geom == "auto"] <- "point
```

which deals with this.

`qplot(1:100)` will be parsed as `qplot(x = 1:100)` (using positional matching), and is dealt with by

```
  if (missing(y)) {
        geom[geom == "auto"] <- "histogram"
        if (is.null(ylab)) 
            ylab <- "count"
    }
```

Comment: @Josh, can you make your comment an answer? I think this is the one I was looking for.

Comment: @JBT -- Thanks, but I think my answer's actually kind of bad practice. Typing the extra character needed by `qplot(y=1:100)` is definitely worth the improved clarity it'll give to your code.